# Не работает вывод из коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

Привет всем.

Решил написать малюсенький краулер, сразу же возникли небольшие проблемы. 
Вот его код:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Crawler {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> setUrlBase = new HashSet<String>();
        Document doc;
        String BaseUrlTxt = "C://Search/url.txt"; 
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://habrahabr.ru").get();

            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                String UrlLinkHref = link.attr("href");
                if (UrlLinkHref.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
                        setUrlBase.add(UrlLinkHref);
                        for (String strUrlHash : setUrlBase) {
                            writeToBase(BaseUrlTxt, strUrlHash + "\n");
                        }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void exists(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found!");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static String readFromBase(String fileName)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        exists(fileName);
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    file.getAbsoluteFile()));
            try {
                String s;
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(s);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void writeToBase(String fileName, String text) {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);

            try {
                wr.write(text + "\n");
            } finally {
                wr.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вся соль вот тут:

```
if (UrlLinkHref.indexOf("http://") == 0) {
                        setUrlBase.add(UrlLinkHref);
                        for (String strUrlHash : setUrlBase) {
                            writeToBase(BaseUrlTxt, strUrlHash + "\n");
                        }
                }
```

В коллекцию вроде бы все добавляется и выводится без повторяющихся элементов, но при записи в файл обнаруживаю, что создалось много копий одной и той же строки, хотя выводилось в println хорошо.В общем очень много дубликатов появилось в файле, странности.....

Помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый раз после добавления строки в `setUrlBase` вы записываете все значения множества, а надо только данное конкретное значение и только в том случае, если оно еще не содержится в множестве.

Comment: Не совсем понял , что вы написали, имелось в виду добавить это? if(!hashSet.contains(strUrlHash)){

Comment: @IvanS Да, но этого недостаточно. Не нужно сохранять весь Set каждый раз.

Comment: Ничеее не понимаю) Только вот одно думаю, вынести саму фор с перебором коллекции за пределы фора элементов ссылок

Comment: @IvanS дерзайте. Код за вас я писать не буду.